# How to change the position of multiple gameObjects with one c# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d game in unity which will have 5 space ship parts scattered across a map right when the game starts. I want to have around 30 coordinates (x, y, z) stored in a file and have 5 random locations be drawn from the file for the 5 pieces. I believe I've figured out how to draw the 5 coordinates, which is shown in the code below. My question is how do I transform the position of multiple gameObjects from this one script?

For example, if I have an array of length 5 filled with coordinates that look like so:

(4,5,0)

(46,-22,0)

(11,23,0)

(96,88,0)

(9,2,0)

How do I assign (4, 5, 0) to gameObject1, (46,-22,0) to gameObject2, etc.

Here is the code I have for the random locations:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //this array holds the randomly generated coordinates
        String [] positionsArray = new String[5]; 
        //this array holds the random numbers to ensure no repeats
        int[] ranNums = new int[5];
        //this integer holds the random number each loop through
        int tempRandom;
        //loop as long as the position array hasn't been filled
        for (int i = 0; i < positionsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            //gets a random number
            tempRandom = getRanNum(0, 15);
            //if the random number has already been chosen redo this loop runthrough
            if (ranNums.Contains(tempRandom))
            {
                i--;
            } else
            {
                //add this random number to the chosen lines
                ranNums[i] = tempRandom;
                // fill the current coordinate element i from line tempRandom of coordinates file
                positionsArray[i] = File.ReadLines("Coordinates.txt").Skip(tempRandom).Take(1).First();
            }
        }
    }

    //This routine gets a random number between the range of
    //lowVal and highVal (both sent in), returning this value as an integer.
    private int getRanNum(int lowVal, int highVal)
    {
        System.Random randGen = new System.Random();

        //To generate a random integer value use this:
        int tempRandom = randGen.Next(lowVal, highVal);

        //returns the random integer
        return tempRandom;
    }
```

Comment: `foreach (var (obj, pos) in gameObjects.Zip(positions)) { Update(...); }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Could you elaborate a bit please? How does this relate to assigning the positions of multiple gameObjects?

Comment: It actually doesn't relate to that specifically the point I'm trying to make is that you can use a generic algorithm like Zip to line up any two collections and go through them pairwise. So if you have an array of positions and an array of game objects you can just go through through them in paris, one at a time

Comment: `new [] {1, 2, 3}.Zip(new [] {"red", "green", "blue"}) // { (1, "red"), (2, "green"), etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty gameobject in the Hierarchy window which will be the parent of all the ship gameobjects you want to position. Then create child gameobjects under the parent for each ship / ship piece. Add this to your existing script:

```
// The children of this gameobject will be positioned in Start method
[SerializeField] private GameObject parent;

void Start()
{
    // existing code goes here...

    // set the positions of the children game objects
    for(var i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount; i++) 
    {
        var child = parent.transform.GetChild(i);
        child.position = positionsArray[i];
    }
}
```

Select the gameobject with this script so you'll see this script in the Inspector window. Then drag the "parent" game object from the Hierarchy to the "parent" field in the Inspector window. When the script runs, it will loop through all the children under the "parent" gameobject and assign their positions. The number of children and positionArray's count must match.